Can I protect myself from Noise Assaulters?
I live in a new building for Seniors.  There is a parking lot across the street where people gather, blasting music and singing.  On the 8th floor, I have recorded this at up to 130db.  That's as loud as a Jet Plane.  The subwoofers hurt my chest.  I'm 71 with cancer. Police refuse to act.  Yet noise like this creates heart attacks, strokes, high blood pressure, diabetes, etc.  We've hjad tenants taken away by ambulance.  Police think noise is a trivial issue.  We are physically sick. It actually hurts. I am desperate.  I want to go out and tell them to leave and if. not use tear gas. The noise is assault and harming people.  Can I do this in self-defense?  Can I call 911 (that ignores them) and let them know that I will be teargassing them? I am desperate. This is self-defense.  70 db is the noise limit. 80 is 10x 70.  90 is 100x louder.....  My walls and floors shake.  I have to protect myself and don't have the energy or money to move.

We cannot give legal advice on this site.

@NateEldredge An answer commenting on legal background for noise pollution couldf be helpful. I know that according to German law, what OP describes would be illegal (the German keyword is Lärmbelästigung) and police would act on it if called. OP seems to be in the US and I have no idea what the relevant laws there are but that would be a useful answer to this question.

It would probably be illegal in the US either, but police not acting on nuisance complaints is not unheard of. Involving politicians and press sometimes helps.

@quarague: If OP wants to know about legal background on noise pollution, then they should rewrite the question accordingly.  As stated, the question is whether OP can use physical violence in a specific real-life situation, and we certainly cannot answer that.

Some factual notes

I am fairly certain that loud noises do not cause diabetes.
I am doubtful that equipment connected to the mains grid via standard electrical plugs can produce as much noise/sound as a jet engine; it seems more likely that whichever device recorded this was inaccurate.
Senior residents being taken away by ambulance can have many causes unrelated to noise.

I will be answering based on the hypothetical case where the musical gathering is in fact causing health issues among residents in a manner that is sufficiently well-documented (doctor’s notes etc.) to make a credible case.
Whichever route the hypothetical resident chooses to pursue, they would be well-inspired to drop any embellishments they added to the story, which would otherwise diminish their credibility, and keep to actual documented facts, no matter how emotionally involved they are.
Legal answer
Hire a local legal professional and pursue whichever action they advise against the organizers of those "parties".
In france, that could be a standard civil lawsuit under article 1240 of the civil code. It is very easy to prove faulty conduct based on noise regulations. The hardest part, in theory, is to prove the amount of damage. The hardest part, in practice, is to make the defendants pay up any nontrivial amount. Almost certainly, this lawsuit is a money-loser; but then the deterrence effect might be worth it to the hypothetical plaintiff.
Practical answer
Any choice should be made by a reasonable person familiar with the local context and with more information about this "hypothetical" than a random internet stranger (i.e., me).
Possible low-cost actions include:

writing to the owner of the parking lot, who might be unaware that these "parties" happen (or under which conditions) and more willing to expel the party-goers than to expose themselves to legal liability.
writing to the local elected official with police powers. In france, that would be the mayor.
writing to whichever local-ish elected official seems more likely to advance the case, based on their track record of constituent service, proximity to the community, etc.
writing to a local newspaper to put pressure on the actors above if they do not act.

Definitely non-advisable actions include:

physically assaulting people. This is not self-defense in france (whether loud music is assault is already questionable given the lack of intentionality, but even if it is the suggested action fails self-defense tests of proportionality and necessity).
threatening to do so unless the other person does X (that is some version of extortion / coercion in any legal system).


In Seattle, It is illegal to create noises that measure over 70 db.  It is also illegal to make noise that can be heard over 75 feet away. And it is illegal to amplify sound after 10pm

NIH Article  Govt paper peer reviewd: Noise pollution remains a pervasive health hazard that people encounter ...implicated in many adverse non-auditory health conditions such as hypertension, atherosclerosis, vascular (endothelial) dysfunction and metabolic disorders. There is a growing body of evidence showing that chronic noise exposure is associated with an increased risk of hypercholesterol, adiposity and development of type 2 diabetes. The present study investigated the effect of noise stress on parameters of glucose homeostasis in male rats and possible recovery after noise cessation.
